# How to plot a vertical line on a bar plot in Bokeh?

Tags: bokeh

Based on the first example of the user-guide of Bokeh,

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Span

output_file("bars.html")

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
counts = [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]

p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x=fruits, top=counts, width=0.9)

# these two lines
vline = Span(location='Apples', dimension='height', line_color='blue', line_width=4)
p.renderers.extend([vline])

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.y_range.start = 0

show(p)
```

I am trying to add a vertical line to a bar plot whose x-range are categories. However, this does not seem to be possible, as this raises an error "ValueError: expected a value of type Real, got Apples of type str".

`location='Apples'` does not work as intended as it expected a number.

Comment: By experience with charts, you might better see how to draw a line on a canvas with javascript, as a layer.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to convert the categorical value to the corresponding numeric value on the plot:

```
index = p.x_range.factors.index("Apples")
delta = (p.x_range.end - p.x_range.start)/p.x_range.factors.length;
location = delta/2 + index;
```

If the plot is dynamic (e.g. values are not known when the plot is built), then use an auxiliary JS function to do the conversion:

```
function _value_to_location(x_range, value) {
    var index = x_range.factors.findIndex(x => x == value)
    var delta = (x_range.end - x_range.start)/x_range.factors.length;
    return delta/2 + index;
};

...

vline.location = _value_to_location(figure.x_range, "Apples");
```

Comment: This is a reasonable workaround for now. However, I think that `Span` should accept categorical coordinates directly, and that the fact that it does not is simply an oversight (it may just be a one line fix to turn it on). I encourage you to submit a GH issue around this.

Comment: How does one use this solution? I get this error:

```delta = (p.x_range.end - p.x_range.start)/p.x_range.factors.length,

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'```